# C# drop down access issue using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have issue in accesing drop down item from c# code behind

Scenario:
    i am modifying drop down based on user selection using jquery/ajax call. while accesing the drop down item from code behind, still it retains old list.

Please help to access updated drop down list from c# code behind.

**Sample code**

Jquery code :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "Search.aspx/LoadNewOptions",
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8;',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "",
            success: function (data) {
                 $("#dropdown").empty();              

                $($.parseJSON(data.d)).each(function () {
                    var Option = $('<option />');

                   xOption.attr('value', this.value).text(this.label);
                    $('#dropdown').append(Option);

                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

C# Code behind code :

```
dropdown.SelectedItem.Value.Trim()   // returns old value
```

Alternate Solution:
     Created separate javascript function and store selected item values in hidden variable. No issues in accessing hidden variables from code behind.

Comment: Do you reload your dropdown values at the Page load event, or it's prevented by a check for Postback ? (if (!IsPostBack) { load stuff })

Answer (score 0):

The server has no knowledge of what ensued on the client unless you tell it.

It looks like you are dynamically appending elements to the dropdown. If you rebind the list when the page next executes, it doesn't know that you have modified it on the client.

- hidden field is fine for simple situations
- you can examine the POST and see if it contains a value which does not exist in the list, and if so, add it

Answer (score 0):

The reason your old value didn't change because the server side has no knowledge of the new value.  Unless you post it back to the server it will not be visible.

Comment: Then how it works for hidden controls? It may be issue only with drop down list ...

Comment: Depends on how you defined it.  Is it an ASP.Net control or a pure html control.